# Xamarin autocomplete

Tags: c#, xamarin

Как сделать autocomplete то есть поле ввода, после ввода в которое предлагается схожий текст. Что использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте `XML`-файл с именем `list_item.xm`l и сохраните его в папке `Resources/Layout`. Установите действие сборки этого файла в `AndroidResource`. Измените файл так, чтобы он выглядел следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:textColor="#000">
</TextView>
```

Этот файл определяет простой `TextView`, который будет использоваться для каждого элемента, который появляется в списке.
Откройте `Resources/Layout/Main.axml` и вставьте следующее

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dp">
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country" />
  <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Откройте `MainActivity.cs` и вставьте следующий код для метода `OnCreate ()`

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
  base.OnCreate (bundle);
  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
  AutoCompleteTextView textView =
   FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView> (Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);
  var adapter = 
  new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, Resource.Layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
  textView.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

После того, как представление содержимого будет установлено в макете `main.xml`, виджет `AutoCompleteTextView` будет захвачен из макета с помощью `FindViewById`. Затем инициализируется новый `ArrayAdapter` для привязки макета `list_item.xml` к каждому элементу списка в массив строк `COUNTRIES`. Наконец, `SetAdapter()` вызывается, чтобы связать `ArrayAdapter` с виджетами `AutoCompleteTextView`, чтобы массив строк заполнил список.
Внутри класса `MainActivity` добавьте массив строк

```
static string[] COUNTRIES = new string[] 
{
 "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", 
 "Andorra","Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
 "Argentina","Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria",
 "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium","Belize", 
  "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
 "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana","Brazil",
 "British Indian Ocean Territory","British Virgin Islands",
 "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi","Cote d'Ivoire",
 "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
 "Cayman Islands","Central African Republic", "Chad", 
 "Chile", "China","Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
 "Colombia", "Comoros","Congo"
};
```

Читайте тут про  [Autocomplete Text View](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/autocomplete_text_view/)

Для `Xamarin.Forms` можете читать книгу

> Mark Reynolds "Xamarin Essentials"
>   от страници 157.

Comment: Это для пустого проекта. Как все это дело вставить в мой проект? И использовать виджет в формах xamarin?

Comment: здесь написан пример реализации вашей проблемы а как это интегрировать в ваш проект это вам виднее,проект то ваш ;) главное понять логику постраении такой реализации

Comment: Этот элемент добавляется в android проект, как его использовать если все остальное сделано в xamarin forms - не очень понятно

Comment: исползуйте логику имплементации а не только копируйте код https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422292/7198805

Comment: и что это значит

Comment: значит что с начало надо читать документацию а потом уже написать программу а не на оборот

Comment: что мне нужно прочитать?

Comment: для начало хотя бы написанный ответ читай там найдешь нужные ссылки,и книгу

Comment: то есть мне нужно будет самому написать компонент?